# ASM x64 function pointer not returning the good value

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, function-pointers

I have a problem with function pointers in assembly, even when my function returns a negative number it always sets `rax` to a positive number, I did a minimal reproductible example with a function that compares two integers and it does the same thing:

ASM Function code [EDIT]:

```
global foo

section .data
msg: db `superior\n`
msg_len: equ $-msg

section .text
foo:
    push rbx
    mov rbx, rdi
    mov rdi, 2
    mov rsi, 1
    sub rsp, 8  ; align the stack frame
    call rbx
    add rsp, 8
    test rax, rax   ;[EDIT] correct: test eax, eax
    js  bar
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, msg_len
    syscall

bar:
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, 2
    sub rsp, 8  ; same here
    call rbx
    add rsp, 8
    test rax, rax  ;[EDIT] correct: test eax, eax
    js exit
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, msg_len
    syscall

exit:
    pop rbx   ;restoring initial data of rbx
    ret
```

main.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int (*f)());  //my asm function prototype

int cmp(int i, int j)
{
  printf("%d - %d\n", i, j);
  return(i - j);
}

int main(void)
{
  foo(&cmp);
  return (0);
}
```

The output is:

```
2 - 1
superior
1 - 2
superior
```

But it should be just:

```
2 - 1
superior
```

Compilation:

```
nasm -f elf64 foo.s
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o foo.o
```

Thanks for the help

[EDIT] It didn't work because I checked rax instead of eax, now it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Shouldn't your jump instruction be JG in label foo? JA does not check the Sign Flag.

Comment: @The_aLiEn Maybe, but isn't ja for "jump above" ?

Comment: @The_aLiEn I checked and jg also does the same thing

Comment: yes it is "jump above". But since negative numbers are represented as MSB = 1, the JA condition will always hit when compared to 0, unless the comparand is 0.

Comment: @The_aLiEn But JG doesn't work aswell

Comment: Same thing. In label "bar" there is an unconditional jump to label "foo2" which is then jumping with "ja" again. That should be "JL".

Comment: Your code has multiple ABI violations. It's clobbering `rbx`, which belongs to the caller, without restoring it, and making a function call with `rsp` not aligned mod 16. I'm not sure if these are the source of what you're seeing, but there's really no hope of it working reliably without them fixed.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE What do you mean? how can I restore rbx?

Comment: @Fayeure: Read https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI, the "x86-64" section, for calling conventions.  These are essential to know and follow.  `rbx` is a callee-saved register, and you must preserve it; that is, you must ensure that when your function returns, that `rbx` contains the same value as when the function was entered.  You could push it on the stack at the beginning of your function and pop it at the end (which would take the place of your stack adjustment).  But simpler would just be to use a caller-saved "scratch" register instead; any of `rax, rcx, rdx, r8, r9, r10, r11` would do.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, that was what caused a segfault in my other function, now it's solved!

Comment: Note that testing the sign bit of `x - y` does *not* tell you which one is greater, if they might be big enough for the subtraction to overflow.  That's why the `jge` condition is `OF == SF`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc.  This cmp function isn't a true comparison; it would have to sign extend its inputs to `int64_t` and return that type if you want to be able to use the sign of its result like you would `cmp x,y` / `jge`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Of course but here it's not the cmp function that is important, it's just a scratch function to see if my assembly code works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `int` is 32 bits, but `rax` is a 64-bit register.  A function that returns `int` will place its return value in `eax`, which will typically zero out the high half of `rax`.  So if `cmp` returns `-1`,  which is the 32-bit number `0xffffffff`, then `rax` will contain `0x00000000ffffffff`.  This is not a negative 64-bit number, so `test rax, rax` will not set the sign flag.

Try using `test eax, eax` as your test instead.

Comment: THANKS You are litteraly the god of Stack Overflow dude it was that :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems too complicated.

Firstly, let's write the thing to do in language like C:

```
int foo(int (*f)()) {
  if (cmp(2, 1) > 0) {
    PRINT;
  }
  if (cmp(1, 2) > 0) {
    PRINT;
  }
}
```

Then, let's write assembly code according to this:

```
global foo

section .data
msg: db `superior\n`
msg_len: equ $-msg

section .text
  ; int foo(int (*f)()) {
foo:
  mov rbx, rdi   ; function pointer stored in rbx
  ;   if (cmp(2, 1) > 0) {
  mov rdi, 2     ; first integer
  mov rsi, 1     ; second integer
  call rbx       ; call function pointer
  cmp rax, 0
  jle bar        ; jump if rdi <= rsi (signed)
  ;     PRINT;
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg
  mov rdx, msg_len
  syscall        ; write "superior\n"
  ;   }
bar:
  ;   if (cmp(1, 2) > 0) {
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, 2
  call rbx
  cmp rax, 0
  jle bar2
  ;     PRINT;
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg
  mov rdx, msg_len
  syscall        ; write "superior\n"
  ;   }
bar2:
  ; }
  ret
```

To retain your code, points to fix are:

- `ja` is for unsigned comparision. `jg` should be used to signed comparision instead.
- There are code to print after `bar2`, but there also are code to print after the jump `ja bar2` is not taken. You should add `ret` before `bar:` to prevent this from being executed.

Comment: Edited, I wrote the code in the post by hand because i'm on a virtual machine I forgot that line but it's not that

Comment: I want to compare two times that's why `jmp foo2`

Comment: It's not because I forgot cmp, it does the same thing with `cmp rax, 0`

Comment: @Fayeure Your `cmp` will print `x - x`, so you should do one comparision without that to compare twice while printing `x - x` only once.

Comment: I'm printing `x - x` just to show that it calls the function but doesn't return the good value, without that the output is just
`superior`
`superior`
and I have the same problem

Comment: I tried to use jg, jle and js and it does the same thing, i think the problem comes from rax that is not taking the good value

Comment: This is still testing 64-bit RAX after calling a function that returns 32-bit `int`, incorrectly assuming the return value will be sign-extended to 64-bits.  Some calling conventions for non-x86 ISAs (like MIPS) require that, but x86-64 calling conventions don't.